# Cron in laravel (using https://github.com/liebig/cron)

Tags: php, laravel, cron

Okay so I have installed https://github.com/liebig/cron
Everything with this is working etc...

I am having trouble with implementing this though.
In my laravel/app/start/global.php

I put this:

```
Event::listen('cron.collectJobs', function() {
    Cron::add('deposit_reminder', '* * * * *', function() {
        foreach (Site::where('org_id', Auth::user()->organization->id)->get() as $site){    
            foreach (Game::get() as $game) {    
        ALOT MORE CORE IS HERE thats not really relevant to see

        Cron::setEnableJob('deposit_reminder');

        return null;
    });
});
```

With this code in global.php I think what is happening is that I am trying to user Auth::user()-> etc... however at this point the login would not have been fired yet because this is upon laravel starting up I think?

I have tried to put this code into routes.php and upon successful login this cron job would get created but when I do this it seems to not create the job for the cronjob... Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what to do instead of using Auth::user, simply just needed to loop over the users model, so do a User::get() and than can use that to loop through each user and send an email based on criterias in the database.

Works flawlessly and I hope this helps someone else in the future.